# Is Kerberos (GSS API) supported by iOS 5 or 6?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, kerberos, gssapi

I think I've dig SO through but haven't found proper answer. Some people here say that there is no support for Kerberos in iOS, however, following links and findings seems to point to opposite direction.

Apple says there is somewhat support for GSS API in iOS.
But Apple documentation is rather poor on this topic, surprisingly. There is remark in the [What's New in iOS 5: General System Security Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1), referencing RFC 2743 (which is all about GSS API including Kerberos) and header files for more details. One line can be seen in [iOS Technology Overview: Device Frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH6-SW3)

When you look at `/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/Headers` you can find these headers there:

- `gssapi_krb5.h`
- `gssapi_netlogon.h`
- `gssapi_ntlm.h`
- `gssapi_spnego.h`
- `gssapi.h`

#### Excerpt from gssapi_krb5.h:

```
...
/*
 * kerberos mechanism specific functions
 */

struct krb5_ccache_data;

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION gss_krb5_copy_ccache
(OM_uint32 * /*minor*/,
 gss_cred_id_t /*cred*/,
 struct krb5_ccache_data * /*out*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_ccache_name(OM_uint32 * /*minor_status*/,
             const char * /*name */,
             const char ** /*out_name */);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION gsskrb5_register_acceptor_identity
        (const char * /*identity*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION krb5_gss_register_acceptor_identity
    (const char * /*identity*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gsskrb5_extract_authz_data_from_sec_context
    (OM_uint32 * /*minor_status*/,
     gss_ctx_id_t /*context_handle*/,
     int /*ad_type*/,
     gss_buffer_t /*ad_data*/);

/*
 * Function declarations
 */

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_export_lucid_sec_context(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                  gss_ctx_id_t *context_handle,
                  OM_uint32 version,
                  void **kctx);


OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_free_lucid_sec_context(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                void *kctx);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_set_allowable_enctypes(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                gss_cred_id_t cred,
                OM_uint32 num_enctypes,
                int32_t *enctypes);

GSSAPI_CPP_END
...
```

So one would expect that there must be some support. As I'm SO rookie and have low reputation at the moment, I can provide only two links. Although I've read instructions how to write good questions, help me improve my question if you feel it is needed, please.

Comment: Can't you run your app on iOS 5.0 and 6.0 simulators and see what happens?

Comment: I'm lost a little. How does running my app in simulators give me info about GSS API presence in iOS and about how to implement it?. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH/Kerberos not working on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023126/ssh-kerberos-not-working-on-osx)

Comment: @PaulSweatte not a dupe.  This question is about iOS, not OS X.