# SSH/Kerberos not working on OSX

Tags: macos, authentication, ssh, kerberos, gssapi

So I have tried and tried to get my ssh to work with kerberos on Mavericks to no avail. Here are my versions:

```
ssh: OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
kerberos: Heimdal 1.5.1apple1
```

I also tried the built in ssh with no effect as well. Here is my config:

```
ForwardAgent yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
```

i have checked, there are no overriding settings in my user config

After all of this, I still get prompted for a password when ssh'ing to a linux host that does work with linux clients. (I am able to successfully kinit and i do get a ticket)

Any clues what I am missing? Has anyone has this problem before.

[HERE](http://pastebin.com/thnpbnyp) is a link to the ssh connection log. It just seems to abandon gssapi without even trying it... why????

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454141/32453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE ON OSX SIERRA:**

*It appears that Apple broke it again.... The gssapitrusdns stuff is actually a third-party contribution and Apple revved to a newer ssh that doesn't include those patches... See [HERE](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1008) and [HERE](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30943936#30943936)*

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (pre Sierra):**

Ok, so after even more head-scratching, giving up, and violent attempts to strangle my computer with a power cord, I have found the answer... Turns out, OSX need to be told to explicitly trust DNS.... Add the following line to your ssh config:

```
GSSAPITrustDNS yes
```

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20180826184023/https://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/sshGSSAPI.html) (check the 'Problems and Workarounds' section)

Comment: `Bad configuration option: gssapitrustdns` in Sonoma.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like server is sending "gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic" methods but somehow client doesn't have support for it. 
Look at this logs

```
preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

can you check your client whether it supports it or not ?
you can check client config file /user//.ssh/config -> on linux system.

Comment: I have. There is support. It is enabled in my system config

Comment: Also, just because it isnt preferred doesnt mean its not supported. The log says that gssapi is part of the 'remaining auth methods until the last try, when it just disappears...

Comment: As per SSH code, preferred the one list which is being negotiated to other party or taken into consideration when other party sends its preferred list.  openssh picks one by one method from its preferred list and compare it with other party preferred list and when both matches first, it selects that as first attempt. It goes on second if first fails. .... if you are sure above is not the case then provide server and client logs at same time. We may get some pointers from that.

Comment: unfortunately, ssh server logs aren't something i can give. I tried forcing the preferred method to be gssapi-with-mic thusly: ssh -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic user@foo.net

It still doesn't work....