# After update Mac OS Sierra, Can not use ssh login remote system,how can I fix this?

Tags: macos, ssh

when I use `user@ip` to login remote system, it report like this:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 17: Applying options for *
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 20: Bad configuration option: gssapikeyexchange
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 21: Bad configuration option: gssapitrustdns
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

Comment: Apple should NEVER have removed previously valid options, but should have 'deprecated' them, and treated them as 'ignored', meaning as though they hadn't been given. Having to turn them into comments is ludicrous. My Kerberos usage was unaffected eliminating GSSAPIKeyExchange.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Comment the following lines in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
from

```
# System-wide defaults set by MIT Kerberos Extras
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
  GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
  GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
```

to

```
# System-wide defaults set by MIT Kerberos Extras
#Host *
#  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#  GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
#  GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
```

Comment: Only comment this if your server is not using GSSAPI for Authentication

Comment: And for those of us that *want* to use Kerberos (GSSAPI) ?

Comment: This answer is close, but not quite accurate. For me, I had to open `~/.ssh/config` and comment out the "GSSAPI" lines in that file.

Comment: I had to also comment out gssapitrustdns as well for this to work for me.

Comment: Wait..do you make this change to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the client or on the server?

Comment: For those that want to use Kerberos, see my other answer below...also frequently the lines to comment out are in ~/.ssh/config FWIW

Answer (score 11):

Since apple removed this functionality, you can still build your own local copy of openssh that is compatible with gssapi (via adding some gssapi patches).

```
$ brew tap rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi

$ brew install rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi/openssh-patched --with-gssapi-support
```

then restart your terminal session and you should be in business.  It creates a new /usr/local/bin/ssh executable that is Kerberos fluent, and, with typical install of homebrew, that one should end up first in your PATH so the one used by default now.  There are also some other patch options to that tap as well (`--with-hpn` faster for large files, and `--with-keychain-support`) see it's [README](https://github.com/rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi) if interested.

Background: If you still want Kerberos ticket functionality (i.e. ssh without identity key file *and* without having to enter password), or the "hpn openssh patch" (purportedly speeds up large file transfer) or the "keychain patch", here's a way to install your own copy of a version of openssh that supports them (this happens to also overcome the OP's problem):

We'll use homebrew for it.

Turns out that homebrew "used to" support an openssh install option called `--with-gssapi-support` that would give you an ssh/scp that supported kerberos tickets.

This may have been removed inadvertently with their [update](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/commit/4ceb4c3e6e2cbb0f2e043363c44a6040dd855761) to version 6.6p1 of openssh [?] . Some tickets have been [proposed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/pull/583) to "re add it" since then, but the maintainers went through a fiasco of some kind with the "keychain" patch and they've resolved to try and keep their openssh formula much more vanilla than they used to, so rejected subsequent proposals.

They suggest creating a "tap" if you want the patches back. [See above for one](https://github.com/rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi) with the patches available.

Another option is to use ssh identity key files (authentication/authorized keys) instead of Kerberos, then you can still use the default provided ssh as is.

Another alternative is to use macports openssh package, which has good support for openssh with Kerberos (as an install option), similar to the homebrew tap mentioned. `sudo port install openssh +gsskex` but the `kinit` it puts on the PATH doesn't support `--keychain` which is a bit more painful.

Comment: My eyes lit up when I saw this solution. However, when I tried to brew install, it failed. Following are few lines from error message: `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain`, `Error: Failed to download resource "openssh--patch"`, `Download failed: https://sources.debian.net/data/main/o/openssh/1:7.5p1-5/debian/patches/gssapi.patch`

Comment: OK appears they let their SSH keychain expire, I moved the patch inline now, should be working.  If not file an issue.

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve this question is copy a ssh binary from an older Mac and place this binary in path before /usr/bin/ssh, ex: (copy from el capitan box) /usr/bin/ssh => ~/bin/ssh, then add $HOME/bin to your PATH before anything else.

The reason is GSSAPITrustDNS and GSSAPIKeyExchange patches are no longer applied by apple, Starting with Sierra when they upgraded OpenSSH to 7.2p2, So one options is to downgrade to the old OS version, if you have to use kerberos＋ ssh.

Comment: Is this really true? One would think that this would be in their release notes (http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7)...

Comment: apparently this isn't an OpenSSH issue but an apple one? http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=147850754710753&w=2

Comment: This is the only solution that helped me.  -1 to Apple for cutting us out of our servers without so much as a warning.  If I did not have a friend with older versions of the ssh binaries I would have been in big trouble.

Answer (score 5):

You probably just need to disable GSSAPITrustDns in the ssh config.  The following snippet does it by adding a `#` before the line:

> vi ~/.ssh/config
>
> :%s/GSSAPITrustDns/# GSSAPITrustDns/g
>
> :wq

Similarly, comment other options also, like gssapikeyexchange etc.

Answer (score 4):

One line answer - run this to remove the GSSAPITrustDns line:

```
sed -i".backup"  '/GSSAPITrustDns/d' ~/.ssh/config
```

Creates a copy & updates : ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Fix for SSH 10.12:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Comment out with a #:

- GSSAPIKeyExchange no
- GSSAPITrustDNS no
- type Control+o
- type Control+x

Answer (score 0):

1. My config `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` was ok and was never changed, I found in ~/.ssh/config the rows I needed to change and it solve that issue.
2. if you are getting:

> Permissions 0644 for ‘~/.ssh/id_rsa[your file]’ are too open

run: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa[your file]` to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to remove ~/.ssh/config file. It worked for me!

Comment: Can you explain why the whole file should be removed? Shouldn't it be fine to just remove the lines in question, as described by other users, and keep the remaining configuration?